# Subset a dataframe according to matches between dataframe column and separate character vector in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, subset

I want to use a chacracter vector to:

1. Find rows in a dataframe that contain single or greater matches to this vector in a comma delimited list within a column of the dataframe
2. Subset the dataframe retaining only the rows with matches

Example data

```
look<-c("ID1", "ID2", "ID5", "ID9")
df<-data.frame(var1=1:10, var2=3:12, var3=rep(c("","ID1,ID3","ID1,ID9","","")))
df
   var1 var2    var3
1     1    3        
2     2    4 ID1,ID3
3     3    5 ID1,ID9
4     4    6        
5     5    7        
6     6    8        
7     7    9 ID1,ID3
8     8   10 ID1,ID9
9     9   11        
10   10   12
```

Where the output would look like:

```
    var1 var2    var3
1    2    4 ID1,ID3
2    3    5 ID1,ID9
3    7    9 ID1,ID3
4    8   10 ID1,ID9
```

The match between the `var3` column could be greater than 1 value from the `look` vector.

Is there a base r solution that doesn't involve using `strsplit` on the `var3` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Create the appropriate regular expression and perform a grep.  As requested this does not use any packages and does not use `strsplit`:

```
subset(df, grepl(paste0("\\b", paste(look, collapse = "|"), "\\b"), var3))
```

giving:

```
  var1 var2    var3
2    2    4 ID1,ID3
3    3    5 ID1,ID9
7    7    9 ID1,ID3
8    8   10 ID1,ID9
```

**1a)** Depending on precisely what `var3` and `look` contain it may be possible to shorten it to just this (but it is less general than the longer one above -- for example `ID1` would also match `ID11` if we used this but the prior solution does not have this problem):

```
subset(df, grepl(paste(look, collapse = "|"), var3))
```

**2)** If you are willing to relax the `strsplit` requirement then this still does not use any packages:

```
subset(df, sapply(strsplit(as.character(var3), ","), function(x) any(x %in% look)))
```

Answer (score 0):

**1**)
We can use `filter` with `str_detect` in `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(stringr)
 df %>% 
   filter(str_detect(var3, paste(look, collapse="|")))
 #    var1 var2    var3
 # 1    2    4 ID1,ID3
 # 2    3    5 ID1,ID9
 # 3    7    9 ID1,ID3
 # 4    8   10 ID1,ID9
```

NOTE: Only one method is provided.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same with base R using grepl function as above OP done

```
 df <- df[grepl("\\,",df$var3),]
  var1 var2    var3
2    2    4 ID1,ID3
3    3    5 ID1,ID9
7    7    9 ID1,ID3
8    8   10 ID1,ID9
```